# Python manipulate timeseries data in aggregation

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, aggregation

I have a  timeseries dataframe which contains the columns as shown below:

```
    perf_date  pull_date  clicks  conv      rev 
    2019-01-21 2019-01-28   56     9        44.12
    2019-01-22 2019-01-28   56     10       44.70
               2019-01-29   56     10       44.70
    2019-01-23 2019-01-28   59     13       89.31
               2019-01-29   59     13       89.31
               2019-01-30   59     14       95.31
```

what I want to do is:
1) Keep all row values of the first row against each perf_date. 
2) Append the values of revenue for the largest pull_date against each perf_date.
So after the manipulation the above dataframe should be like this:

```
    perf_date  pull_date  clicks  conv      rev 
    2019-01-21 2019-01-28   56     9        44.12
    2019-01-22 2019-01-28   56     10       44.70
    2019-01-23 2019-01-28   59     13       95.31
```

Comment: What is `print (df.index)` ?

Comment: I used a groupby method earlier and then reset index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with dictionary of columns with aggregate functions - you can pass it manually or dynamic - all columns without `perf_date` and `rev` are aggregate by `first` and `rev` by `last`:

```
#if necessary
df['perf_date'] = df['perf_date'].ffill()
df = df.sort_values(['perf_date','pull_date'])

d = dict.fromkeys(df.columns.difference(['perf_date','rev']), 'first')
d['rev'] = 'last'
print (d)
{'clicks': 'first', 'conv': 'first', 'pull_date': 'first', 'rev': 'last'}

df = df.groupby('perf_date', as_index=False).agg(d).reindex(df.columns, axis=1)
print (df)
    perf_date   pull_date  clicks  conv    rev
0  2019-01-21  2019-01-28      56     9  44.12
1  2019-01-22  2019-01-28      56    10  44.70
2  2019-01-23  2019-01-28      59    13  95.31
```

EDIT:

```
d = dict.fromkeys(df.columns.difference(['perf_date','rev']), 'first')
df1 = df.groupby('perf_date', as_index=False).agg(d)
s = df.groupby('perf_date')['rev'].nth(2)
df = df1.join(s, on='perf_date')
print (df)
    perf_date  clicks  conv   pull_date    rev
0  2019-01-21      56     9  2019-01-28    NaN
1  2019-01-22      56    10  2019-01-28    NaN
2  2019-01-23      59    13  2019-01-28  95.31
```

Comment: excellent solution. What if I want to keep the third row for all columns except revenue? Is that possible easily?

Comment: @Nofy - then is possible use [`GroupBy.nth`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.nth.html), check edited  answer.

Comment: actually you picked the third revenue value, I wanted to keep the third row of all other columns and the last revenue value